# SwiftUI: What does it mean to drive a NavigationLink presentation with state?

Tags: swiftui

I am currently unable to replicate all of the various navigation patterns I need for my app.  While trying out a few suggestions, I came across the three NavigationLink initializers in the SwiftUI headers. The first signature is very common, but what are the second and third initializers used for and why (and how) would they each be used?

Thanks.

```
/// Creates an instance that presents destination as a detail view.
public init<V>(destination: V, label: () -> Label) where V : View

/// Creates an instance that controls a presentation driven by state.
public init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, label: () -> Label)

/// Creates an instance that controls a presentation driven by state.
public init<V>(destination: V, in presentedDestination: Binding<V?>, label: () -> Label)
```

Comment: We will never know it ever worked ;) I experimented a lot with these with no success. XC Beta 5 brought new interface for `NavigationLink` - can not test until macOS beta is out, but it looks more consistent.

Comment: @simpleone You're right. It appears that my navigation issues are now resolved in Beta 5. I am now able to programmatically push and pop navigation and also programmatically dismiss Modals.  FYI, there are "some" issues, but for the most part, I am able to run XC Beta 5 on macOS Beta 4.